# A question about to counter examples in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Given an example that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $V$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$  , but $f(V)$ is not closed $\mathbb{R}$

Given an example that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $V$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$  , but $f(V)$ is not bounded $\mathbb{R}$

***My Idea***

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ on $[0,\infty)$ is closed but image is not closed and also this bounded on  $[0,\infty)$ but image is not bounded.

Am i am right, can anyone give any other examples?

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the condition that $f$ must be defined on the whole real line.

Comment: See if a function is continuous then the inverse image of any closed  (or open) set  is closed (or open). So try to find a continuous function whose inverse is not continuous.

Answer (score 3):

For #1 you could take $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$ with any unbounded closed set $V$.

The second is impossible: the closure of a bounded set is compact, a continuous function maps compact sets to compact sets, and compact sets are bounded.